# Handle APNS Remote Notifications while in Background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented all recommended methods in AppDelegate to get working Remote Notifications service.

I can accept them while running, while launching and while turned off.

But there is an issue, since I can't work with many received notifications while in background. I can work only with latest notification.

What is recommended manual to do that? How can I got all notifications received while in background? Is it only solvable via manual call to my service provider (sender of apns data)?

Comment: If you're truly implementing APNS correctly, your app never "handles" the notification. iOS receives all of the notifications, and the user can use those notifications to open your app. That's it.

Comment: The notification system isn't intended to be used to send important data between the server and the device. It's just meant to bump the device so it can contact the server and find out what's actually going on. Aside from not being suited to this push notifications also aren't reliable enough to do anything important. If server load is an issue for you, then increase the price of your app or something to cover it. Users will be happy to pay if your app is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With all the projects I've worked on there hasn't been a way to locally store this information if the push notification is dismissed. In all those cases we used a small file on the server that the app would connect to and pull when it became active again. There was also some place in the app where the user could see all their notifications which, again, were stored on the server for quick retrieval.

With the way I understand push notifications to be setup, if the notification is dismissed the system discards it. It'll perform anything it's supposed to do (such as update the badge number and play the correct sound) but any additional information specific to that notification is lost.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What I wonder about is, that when application is in foreground, push notification is delivered right to AppDelegate. But when I'm running long task in background, I'd like to receive these notifications too. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. From everything I've worked with we've always had to go to the server to get 'missed' notifications. If the notification was dismissed while the app was in the background the only thing to change was the badge number.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps, but if you just want to know how many notifications you have missed while you were in background. You can create a variable which contains notification number and store this in the app every time you handle notification. When you come out of background and receive a new notification you can subtract the new number with the stored number to find out the number of missed notifications. I don't think there is a way where iOS can give you complete data associated with all the notification device have received while the app was in background.

Comment: good suggestion, but I'm looking for way how to store them locally, because it's heavy on server in my situation to get notifications after some notifications id for client token id...

Comment: do you want to store information received in push locally when the app is in background?

Comment: @Nilesh yeah, I'd like to store received notifications, while my app is running long task in background.

Comment: @MarekSebera I don't think iOS allows that. You will have to handle it using your server as suggested by Thomas Hajcak. Just use push notification to let your app know that new data is available and then pull data from server.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to keep a list of sent notifications with all relevant data on your server, so the app can access that data when it launches. Sending multiple notifications with data that is not stored on the server can be risky, because the application only receives the notification when the user opens the app **from that notification**, so if they tap on one notification, the app will only every receive that one.

If you have them all in a list on your server, the app can simply go and pull that list down, and process it, making sure no data is lost.