# How to get the payload for an APN when there is more than one of them stacked up?

Tags: ios

Consider this scenario:

1. An application is currently not in the foreground but it is in the background in an unsuspended state (appDidEnterbackground: was called)
2. The device receives 3 APNs for the application, and the user has the alert style set as "Alerts"
3. The user clicks Launch on the topmost (4th alert) showing notification alert
4. didReceiveRemoteNotification: is called and the app can get the payload of that particular notification
5. The app is now in the foreground with the alert dialog (for the other 3 notifications) displayed on top of it
6. The user clicks Launch on the notification alert (the 3rd alert)  - nothing happens
7. The user clicks Lunch on the notification alert again (the 2nd alert)  - still nothing happens
8. The user clicks Launch on the last notification alert (which was the 1st one received by the device) - applicationDidBecomeActive: is called.

So my question is how can the application get the payload for the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd notifications?

I can reproduce this 100%, I've noticed that didReceiveRemoteNotification: gets called for the last notification that the device received, and applicationDidBecomeActive get's called for the 1st, with nothing happening for any in the middle.

i.e. if 7 notifications are sent to the device, then didReceiveRemoteNotification: would get called for the 7th, then when the user clicks on Launch for the 6th, 5th, 4th, 3rd, and 2nd alert dialogs nothing would happen, then when they click on Launch for the last dialog (which was for the first notification received) then applicationDidBecomeActive: is called.

Comment: I think that you can't get the payload of the previous notifications and it's kind of the expected behavior. The aim of such notification is to inform the user that there is something new in your app and to push him to open your app (which is done when he clicks on launch on the top notification alert.  
It seems like you need the data in the payload of the other notifications though it's not a good practice to carry important data in the notification. You should be able to know what is new for the user when he opens the app with the last notification (or without).

Comment: And maybe you can precise what you are trying to do with the notification payload (what is your use case) ?

Comment: That's what I suspected, but was hoping otherwise. THanks. Do you know if there's any way for the app to find out how many notifications there are in the notification history, I also suspect there isn't but hopefully...

Comment: This is usually done on server side. The server keeps tracks of how many notifications/new data there are. Each time there is a new thing to send, you can increment a value somewhere for your user. And when you send the notification you can set the badge value to the number of new things there are for your user to retrieve. The badge value in the notification payload will automatically set the badge on the icon app. And when you receive the last notification you can get that value from the notification dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers. The best way to store it on the server and read it from there.

Just one more reference to the very similar question/answers:

[Handle APNS Remote Notifications while in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599704/handle-apns-remote-notifications-while-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this payload. You might also consider, that APNs don't have a guaranteed delivery so you must get infos from the server anyway. The push data is for stuff like showing the user a specific view of your app. In the logic part of your app, the push should only trigger a force update with your server's data.